# Inserting to two different models related to USER

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three models. `User` `Chat` and `Message`
They have their respective tables.

Is this the right way in inserting?

I've managed to insert data to this nested relationship but I don't think it's good.

user table

```
id|name|email|other fields
```

chat table

```
id|user_id|receiver_id
```

message table

```
id|chat_id|message|created_at|updated_at|
```

`user one to many relationship to chat`

`chat one to many relationship to message`

```
        $chat = new Chat;
        $message = new Message;

        $chat->receiver_id = request('receiver_id');
        $message->message = request('message');

        $user->chats()->save($chat);
        $chat->messages()->save($message);
```

I expect data would be saved in more cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for my previous answer. Here is the single statement you could use instead of newing up the models and assigning the values one by one:

```
$user->chats()->save(new Chat(['receiver_id' => request('receiver_id')]))
     ->messages()->save(new Message(['message' => request('message')]));
```

With the `create()` method, you can simplify further:

```
$user->chats()->create(['receiver_id' => request('receiver_id')])
     ->messages()->create(['message' => request('message')]);
```

Hope that helps.